# Создание собственной карты OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

передо мной стоит задача добавить в мобильное приложение карту небольшой местности, я остановился на osm.

Знаю я о ее существовании не так давно, и буду очень благодарен если поможете

Я хочу взять osm, вырезать нужный мне фрагмент, сохранить его у себя, внести какие-то изменения и добавить в моб. приложение, это реально сделать вообще, если да, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как?